# E1 and E2 are equivalent then they are "almost equivalent"

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, relation-algebra

Given : 2 statements E1, E2 in relational algebra are "almost equivalent" if every phase in the database D ,except finite number of D's E1(D)=E2(D). E(D) means the result of activating the statement E on database D.

We have to prove that if E1 and E2 are equivalent then they are also "almost Equivalent". How to prove so? I've tried with negation but it didn't worked well. Then I used straight forward the term of equivalence between two relationals, but it seems not finite prove.

Can you guide me how to start the proof?

Comment: what's the $\text{def}^n$ of equivalent?

Comment: E1 and E2 are equivalent (E1≡E2) if foreach snapshot of the database D,
compute E1 on D results with the same tuples(rows) as compute E2 on D.